# If Perl already links to libm, why aren't any of the functions exposed to the user?

Tags: perl, math, floor, ceil, libm

Perl already links to `libm`.

```
$ ldd $(which perl)
    ...
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd8ce2ea000)
    ...
```

So if Perl already links to `libm`, why aren't often used features like `ceil`, `floor`, and `pow` provided as `CORE::GLOBAL`s or provided in another namespace? Why does `perldoc -q ceil` point to `POSIX.pm` as a source for this function, and why does [`Math::Libm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Libm) even exist?

Python also links to `libm` which is exposed to the user when you run `import math` with the symbols available in the module `math` and can be referenced from outside like `math.ceil(num)`

Comment: Could be portability, could be cause noone bothered to do it, could be that they thought a module would be better than a monolithic set of ops. Of course, there's the whole backwards compatibility aspect. Maybe someone thought of it before 5.10 added a mechanism for adding new ops safely.

Comment: Perl already has far too many built-in functions to keep track of; why not put most of the math functions in a module to help keep things cleanish?

Comment: These functions in libm are part of the POSIX standard.  Perl bundles everything defined by POSIX into the POSIX library whether or not it's available in CORE::.

Answer (score 0):

Perl *does* have maths functions built in: just its idea of the functions you might need are on par with a 1970s minicomputer. There are all the ones I could find:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# maths_builtins.pl - some (all?) of the libm functions built in to Perl
# scruss - 2021-05

my $val = -1.234;

print 'abs(', $val, ')', "\t=  ", abs($val), "\n";

my $pi = 4 * atan2( 1, 1 );
print '4*atan2(1,1)', "\t=  ", $pi, "\t(= π)", "\n";
print 'cos(π/6)', "\t=  ", cos( $pi / 6 ), "\n";

my $e = exp(1);
print 'exp(1)', "\t\t=  ", $e, "\t(= e)", "\n";
print 'int(', $val, ')', "\t= ", int($val), "\n";
print 'log(e)', "\t\t=  ", log($e), "\n";
print 'sin(π/6)', "\t=  ", sin( $pi / 6 ), "\n";
print 'sqrt(3)/2', "\t=  ", sqrt(3) / 2, "\n";
print 'sqrt(3)**2', "\t=  ", sqrt(3)**2, "\n";
exit;
```

resulting in:

```
abs(-1.234)     =  1.234
4*atan2(1,1)    =  3.14159265358979     (= π)
cos(π/6)        =  0.866025403784439
exp(1)          =  2.71828182845905     (= e)
int(-1.234)     = -1
log(e)          =  1
sin(π/6)        =  0.5
sqrt(3)/2       =  0.866025403784439
sqrt(3)**2      =  3
```

Note that instead of a `pow()` function, Perl has the `**` operator, just like FORTRAN does. You don't get a `tan()` function, because that's `sin($x)/cos($x)`. If you need other transcendental functions, that's why they put the [trigonometric functions table](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp8/handbooks/programmingLanguages_May70.pdf) (PDF, p.39) in all good programming books.

I can't recall ever using or needing `ceil()` or `floor()` myself, but Perl missing `sgn()` as a builtin gets me every time. Since Perl is a typeless scripting language at heart, numeric gardening tasks like rounding can already be done with string functions such as `sprintf "%.f", $val`.

Comment: There's also the core `Math::Trig` module in addition to the functions in `POSIX`.

Comment: but that's an add-on library. The functions and operator above are built-in, no `use` required

Comment: Note that `sprintf` returns a string, and on perls compiled with `USE_LOCALE_*` the value can be locale dependent.

Comment: @choroba — and that's a bonus! `perlbrew`-built and Debian-derived Perls have USE_LOCALE_* set.

Comment: But it means you can't use `sprintf` for rounding, unless it's the last step.

Comment: @choroba how would that affect a number with no separators or decimal point?

Comment: You are probably right as `%f` seems to only use the radix character and to ignore the grouping character.