# Is it possible to write an XS module when the shared library is already mapped into the process space?

Tags: perl, linker, xs, libm

This is on the limits of what I know, please correct any confusion here. [In this question I ask why functionality provided by `libm` isn't already exposed to the user with a Perl interface.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67643693/124486) Now I want to know how it's done.

There is a module on CPAN that claims to do called [`Math::Libm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Libm). This works fine, but as a question on implementation when I use this I find that not just is libm mapped into the process as with any running Perl interpreter on Debian,

```
7f719246d000-7f719247c000 r--p 00000000 fe:01 86513750                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
7f719247c000-7f7192516000 r-xp 0000f000 fe:01 86513750                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
7f7192516000-7f71925af000 r--p 000a9000 fe:01 86513750                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
7f71925af000-7f71925b0000 r--p 00141000 fe:01 86513750                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
7f71925b0000-7f71925b1000 rw-p 00142000 fe:01 86513750                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so
```

But `Math::Libm` also maps in another libm shared object,

```
7fb649043000-7fb649044000 r--p 00000000 fe:01 11143927                   /home/ecarroll/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Math/Libm/Libm.so
7fb649044000-7fb649049000 r-xp 00001000 fe:01 11143927                   /home/ecarroll/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Math/Libm/Libm.so
7fb649049000-7fb64904a000 r--p 00006000 fe:01 11143927                   /home/ecarroll/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Math/Libm/Libm.so
7fb64904a000-7fb64904b000 r--p 00006000 fe:01 11143927                   /home/ecarroll/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Math/Libm/Libm.so
7fb64904b000-7fb64904c000 rw-p 00007000 fe:01 11143927                   /home/ecarroll/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/auto/Math/Libm/Libm.so
```

This seems to be because [`Autoloader`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SMUELLER/AutoLoader-5.74/lib/AutoLoader.pm) loads the external shared object.

Is it possible to access the symbols already in the resident process without loading an external shared object?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to access the symbols already in the resident process without loading an external shared object?

You need to<sup>†</sup> load the XS `Libm.so` to access C library functions from Perl, but when `Libm.so` is loaded at runtime using `dlopen()` (see [dl_load_file()](https://metacpan.org/pod/DynaLoader)) the [dynamic loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) will recognize that `Libm.so` requires `libm.so` but since `libm.so` has already been loaded by the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) (when running perl itself), it will not be reloaded but an existing filehandle will be returned, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12148454/2173773) Q&A, so the shared library `libm.so` is not loaded twice.

**Footnotes**:

† : But see also [C::DynaLib](https://metacpan.org/pod/C::DynaLib), and [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus) for alternatives that does not require XS